# MYSQL manual problem varchar with frequent updates

Tags: mysql

MYSQL documentation says this:

"For MyISAM tables that change frequently, you should try to avoid all variable-length columns (VARCHAR, BLOB, and TEXT). The table uses dynamic row format if it includes even a single variable-length column. See Chapter 13, Storage Engines. "

The table I am building will have:
1st column: auto incrementing INT, set as primary key
Then 20 columns of Varchar(255)
3 million rows

The varchar columns will have text entered, usually around 100 characters, but in rare cases up to 255 characters could be entered.  Every read of the table also does an update (data is read, processed and then table updated with new info), hence there is a lot of "change" on the table.  But is this the same change the article quote above refers to?

I have been told this is a non "textbook" setup, but it is built for speed alone, and is ok. so, the question is does the manual quote above mean I should use Char(255) instead of varchar for my needs?

Comment: You may want to clarify: are you reading/updating one row at a time, or many rows at a time?  What indexes do you have on this table?  What is an example of some of the SELECT/UPDATE queries you are running?

Comment: yes, reading/updating 1 row at a time, 1st column is primary key index.  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id='id'.  similar single row update, to same row after processing.

Comment: Ack, an update on every read! Oh, you're asking right questions about row formats and stuff like this. Go on, hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the change that the article is talking about. Char(255) should yield better performance but this will cost diskspace 255 bytes-(actual data length). <strike>Also if you do this you may also have to add trims to your client code.</strike>  
According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

> When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the specified length. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are removed.

So there's no concern about trailing spaces, unless you use the [binary strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-binary-collations.html).

```
For binary strings, all characters are significant in comparisons, 
including trailing spaces: 

mysql> SET NAMES binary;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'a ' = 'a';
+------------+
| 'a ' = 'a' |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Trim removes spaces from the beginning and ends of strings. As far as I know every language has a function that does this. Here is mysql's http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim. You can also do this in your client code (e.g. PHP, Java, .NET)

Comment: What would be its usage here?  The text strings being input into the table are usually 100 to 255 characters and have no spaces at the beginning or end...

Comment: Until you change the fields to char(255). Then spaces may be added on the end to fill out the field. Its really just something to watch out for. Different clients do different things to fixed length strings like char(255)

Comment: @David19801 Mysql trims whitespace automatically. See, what experts answers your questions